# Automating Redshift data dump to a PostgreSQL DB every 12 hours

Tags: postgis, web-mapping, trigger, amazon-web-services

I have a redshift database that changes multiple times a day. I want to use this "live" data to make web maps and I have a Postgres DB where all my web-mapping data is stored. I want to continuously dump data from the ever-changing Redshift DB to my maps via the Postgres DB. Ideally, I'd want it to update every 12 hours at most since I think redshift refreshes every 6hrs. What is the simplest way to do this? I have experience with SQL so if that's the route it would be helpful. No extensive experience with complex server-side systems.

Comment: I'd investigate on dba.stackexchange for questions like this (no geo component...)

Comment: How is your spatial data stored in Redshift, which seems to not be a spatial DB like PostGIS? Is some conversion required, rather than a simple dump/restore across different databases?

Comment: I should have specified the redshift data are non-spatial tables that join to a spatial table already stored in postgres through a key